# Open excel file inside a window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I want to show an excel file inside my wpf window like this:

[image]

if I Create an excel application and then set Visible property to true, Excel application will open and I don't want this behavior.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsxApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook workbook = xlsxApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
xlsxApp.Visible=true; //Excel will open, I don't want this.
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is Excel embedded in a Wpf Control. [This page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9cd139cf-a235-429c-b4db-53075eb40a42/is-there-any-possible-way-to-embed-the-excel-sheet-to-wpf-control?forum=wpf) could be a good start. To sum it up, it must be included in your UI using ActiveX.

There is not pure WPF excel control per se.

If you need to mimic some excel features without the need to open an existing file, there are plenty of "excel like" controls available on the internet free or not. For instance [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691749/Free-NET-Spreadsheet-Control).