# Use excel in WPF application

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF. I have a WPF application and I need to render an already existing excel file(section:-Batch Control Ticket). What I need to show in the WPF app is what exactly appears in the excel file. I know we can do it in a different way by loading the excel file in the C# code and mapping it in to a DataGrid. But it will not give the exact appearance of the file. I have seen some 3rd party availability but I need to purchase them and cannot be sure of their reliability. What can I do? Are there any tool available in WPF or a recommended other? The image shows how I need the app to appear. [image]

Comment: Take a look at this link it might help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646872/open-excel-file-inside-a-window-in-wpf

Comment: @swamy Thanks. But I went through that post before posting this question since I could not find a workable example and some of the linked posts were a little out of date.

Comment: I think security and office changes have made the task of embedding any old app in a wpf window rather harder. Old code no longer works. One possibility is excel online in a webbrowser control. Would that work for you?